# Ag-Grid Highlight Cell based on Value of Column and Column Header

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid with React and Typescript.

The data that I'll have in my ag-grid is as follows:

[image]

This data will be populated from a REST API call. This API call will also return a list of cells that I need to highlight. The response of the REST API call is something like this:

```json
{
  data: [
    {
       Name: "Enola",
       Monday: null,
       Tuesday: 8,
       Wednesday: 0,
       Thursday: -11,
       Friday: -100,
    },
    ...
  ],
  highlight: [
    {
       col: "Tuesday",
       row: "Enola"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is to highlight all the cells specified in the highlight key of the API response. So, basically, in the above-mentioned example, I want to highlight cell C2.

I know that to modify the style of the cell I need to use the `cellStyle` property in `colDef`. But how can I achieve this in my column definition because in `cellStyle` function we only get info related to the column of that cell?

I have a solution in mind that I iterate over the entire data grid and then for each row I check what cell I need to highlight but I think this method will not be a good approach.

So, I am looking for a smart way to do this. Can anyone help me highlight a cell based on the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cell formatting based on rules followed css classes
Below is just an example to help you to understand.

```
 const cellClassRules = {
 "cell-pass": params => 
  params.value >= 60,
 "cell-fail": params => 
  params.value < 60
 };

var gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
{
  cellClassRules: cellClassRules,
  field: "math",
},
{
  cellClassRules: cellClassRules,
  field: "english",
},
{
  cellClassRules: cellClassRules,
  field: "science",
 },
 };



/* style.css */

 .cell-fail {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #f44336;
 }

 .cell-pass {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  }
```

Comment: I need to highlight a cell based on the combination header name and the value of first column for that row. I think this will allow me to highlight it based on value in that particular column and will have no reference for which row I am at.